# Using LESS, is it possible to extend parametric mixins?

Tags: css, less, extend, mixins

I'm new to LESS and I'm just experimenting with it, using version 1.5. I discovered the useful `extend` command, but I was wondering if that could be applied to parametric mixins as well as static ones. Apparently, this doesn't seem possible, based on my experiments:

This works

```
.some-mixin {

}

.child {
  &:extend(.some-mixin);
}
```

This doesn't work and throws an "unexpected token" error:

```
.some-mixin(@color, @bgcolor) {
  color: @color;
  background-color: @bgcolor;
}

.child1 {
  &:extend(.some-mixin(red, blue));
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.child2 {
  &:extend(.some-mixin(red, blue));
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.child3 {
  &:extend(.some-mixin(red, blue));
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Is this a current limitation of LESS, or am I using it incorrectly? Thanks in advance for the answers.

**Edit - Added expected output, as per request**

What I would expect makes more sense when there are more children extending the parametric mixin:

```
.child1,
.child2,
.child3 {
  color: red;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.child2 {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.child3 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently this is not supported. But it's planned to be implemented in future versions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, at least I know I'm not messing things up.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve (that is, I am not sure what you expect the `:extend()` code to actually do if it were extending the parameteric mixin). If your desire is to define the colors of `.child`, then using it as a straight mixin works:

**LESS**

```
.some-mixin(@color, @bgcolor) {
  color: @color;
  background-color: @bgcolor;
}

.child {
 .some-mixin(red, blue);
}
```

**CSS Output**

```css
.child {
  color: #ff0000;
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

**This also makes `.child` itself a mixin for the `red` and `blue` color combination, which I think would have been a net result of the extension working if it had worked.** That is, I would expect your second set of code to have produced something like this (theoretically; this does not actually work nor is it actually produced in LESS):

```
.some-mixin(@color, @bgcolor),
.child(@color: red, @bgcolor: blue) {
  color: @color;
  background-color: @bgcolor;
}
```

But these two are nearly equivalent as mixins (one has the added parameters):

```css
/* theoretical mixin if extension worked */
.child(@color: red, @bgcolor: blue) {
  color: @color;
  background-color: @bgcolor;
}
/* code from straight use of .some-mixin in .child */
.child {
  color: #ff0000;
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

So that either of the above used like so will get the result of mixing in the child values to the new selector:

**LESS**

```
.test {
  .child; /* or using .child(); */
}
```

**CSS Output**

```css
.test {
  color: #ff0000;
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. To clarify, I would expect the `.child` to extend the "concrete" mixin resulting from the evaluation of the parametric call.

Comment: @Diego: I'm not sure your explanation shed any more light on what you were expecting. What final LESS or CSS output result would you have expected?